# multiple screen setup on Ubuntu 19.04 with xrandr

Tags: lubuntu, xrandr

I am using a Surface Pro 6, which has a screen resolution of 2736x1824 (3:2). I want to attach an external monitor which has a screen resolution of 1920x1080 (16:9).

I want to use the Surface Pro 6 as my main screen on the left-hand-side scaled to 200%, so that things won't look too small, and the external monitor on the right-hand-side scaled to 100%, so that things won't look too big. I have searched on the Internet and played with `xrandr`, but none of the commands I tried scales the screens correctly.

Below is one of the commands I have tried:

```
xrandr --fb 6576x3984 --output eDP-1 --mode 2736x1824 --output DVI-I-1-1 --scale 2x2 --pos 2736x0
```

May anyone please help me on this? I am typing this post on the Surface Pro screen with 100% scaled and the text is so small.